# Angular2, how to use @Host on ES6 components

Tags: dependency-injection, angular

I don't see an example on how to use accomplish what Host does (inject parent reference into child) in ES6.

```
@Component({ ... })
class PlayButton {
  constructor(@Host() playerService: PlayerService) {

  }
}
```

Any idea on how we could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Host` variable, which may be used with any Directives.Not sure if there is `@Host decorator`.
Also if you have to inject some service you may use `providers` in the component decorator.

you may look into [Angular API](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/index.html#!?apiFilter=host) for reference.

For Host implementation you may look into [Attribute Directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#respond-to-user) implementation.

**Update**

you may try ContentChildren decorator.

```
 @Directive({
   selector: 'someDir'
 })
 class SomeDir {
   @ContentChildren(ChildDirective) contentChildren: QueryList<ChildDirective>;
   ngAfterContentInit() {
    // contentChildren is set
   }
 }
```

For reference you may check [Angular API](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/index.html#!?apiFilter=content)

Comment: Thx. Im not looking to use Directives on a component to get the reference on that same component. I am just trying to access the parent component of my component.

I want to let it know when something happens in the the child. Also, I can't make the parent listen to an event on the children directly on the template since the template is defined by the user (using ng-content).